# The representation theory of a group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be the $\mathbb KG$-module. Denote by $V^G$ the subspace of $V$ consisting of all the invariant elements under the action of $G,$ i.e., $V^G = \{v\in V| g\cdot v = v\}.$
Consider $W = V/V^G.$ Prove that $W = W^G.$

Clearly, $W^G \subseteq W.$ How to prove $W \subseteq W^G$?  I need some insight!

Comment: You can't prove something that isn't true, so I would't look for insight too hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an easy counterexample let $G = \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$ and $V = \mathbb R^2$ considered as column vectors with the natural left action of matrix multiplication.  Then $V^G = \{0\}$ so $W = V/\{0\} \simeq V$ is $2$-dimensional and $W^G = \{0\}$ again.